# How to find the actual area available to an AIR app on an Android device?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

Is there a way to determine the real area available to an AIR app on an Android device?

For example, on Kindle Fire **Capabilities.screenResolutionY** returns 600 while it's actually about 580 because of the toolbar. Is it possible to arrive to this value programmatically?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm using Flash Pro CS6.  stage.stageHeight returns whatever was set in the Properties panel of Flash Pro. So, this won't work for multiple Android devices unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's correct. check out the docs on stageHeight (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#stageHeight) ... "You can add an event listener for the resize event and then use the stageHeight property of the Stage class to determine the actual pixel dimension of the resized Flash runtime window". My understanding of this is that stageHeight will always reflect the size of the window that flash is running in whether that equals what you put in the properties panel or not.

Comment: Yes, you're right! My mistake was to use `stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL;`. When I changed it to `stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;`, no problem. Thank you.

Comment: hackattack, how can I set your comment as the correct answer?

Comment: i turned my comments into an answer, now you can mark it correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use stage.stageHeight http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#stageHeight

Answer (score 0):

This question is relative. From the hardware side of things, 600 pixels are available so that result should be expected. If you're programming for a Kindle Fire couldn't you just anticipate the 20 pixel toolbar and subtract 20 from the result anytime you need it? That rests on the assumption that your project is specific to the Kindle Fire.

Comment: Kindle Fire is just an example. The app should work on any Android device (within reason of course). I use vector graphics for all assets. Provided that the exact stage size is available, it should be trivial to resize all the assets.

Comment: Yes but the Kindle Fire is so different from true Android that you might not enjoy that luxury. This 'fragmentation' is a pain point of developing for Android-based devices but it's something we all face. I can't think of another Android-based OS skinning that is as aggressive as Amazon with the Kindle Fire, so my guess is your code will work for all Android devices except the Kindle Fire, and that you'll need a second project with some different UI elements in order to deliver the best UX for that platform.

Comment: I know what you mean. My app is actually pretty simple, so I hope it will work on as many Android devices as possible. The reason why I was not getting the right numbers is `StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL;`. Should have used `StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE`.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that question is a bit limited.  AIR code can be (mostly) platform independent, and I would recommend allowing that aspect in programming.  With that in mind, this is as close as I can figure out to a universal solution for sizing.

```
static public const DEVICE_UNK:int = 0;
static public const DEVICE_WINDOWS:int = 1;
static public const DEVICE_APPLE_IPAD:int = 2;
static public const DEVICE_ANDROID:int = 3;

public var deviceType:Number;
public var _fullWidth:Number;
public var _fullHeight:Number;

deviceType = -1;
if (Capabilities.manufacturer.toLowerCase().indexOf("windows") != -1)
{
    deviceType = DEVICE_WINDOWS;
}
else if (Capabilities.manufacturer.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") != -1)
{
    deviceType = DEVICE_ANDROID;
}
else if (Capabilities.manufacturer.toLowerCase().indexOf("ios") != -1)
{
    deviceType = DEVICE_APPLE_IPAD;
}
else
{
    deviceType = DEVICE_UNK;
}
```

And then use `deviceType` to determine the dimensions during initialization, resizing, or whatever:

```
switch (deviceType)
{
    case DEVICE_UNK: 
    case DEVICE_WINDOWS: 
        _fullWidth = stage.stageWidth;
        _fullHeight = stage.stageHeight;
        break;
    case DEVICE_ANDROID: 
    case DEVICE_APPLE_IPAD: 
        _fullWidth = Math.max(stage.fullScreenWidth, stage.fullScreenHeight);
        _fullHeight = Math.min(stage.fullScreenWidth, stage.fullScreenHeight);
        break;
    default: 
        trace("Error: invalid deviceType.");
        break;
}
```

`_fullWidth` and `_fullHeight` are then the current, maximum dimensions of useable space on any platform.

I would love to have any improvements to the code.  No code optimizations, please; I am looking for better ways to determine dimensions.  Please leave a comment if you know better.

Comment: What about `case DEVICE_ANDROID: ` ?

Comment: Oh, I think I understand -- this is a switch-case syntax question.  The code will continue to be executed line by line until the next `break` statement.  So once it finds the match against `DEVICE_ANDROID` it will process each line until the next `break` statement. The Android statement above equivalent to `... else if(deviceType == DEVICE_ANDROID || deviceType == DEVICE_APPLE_IPAD) { ...`

Comment: Oh, my bad :) sorry for missing this. The code still needs a way to handle controls that some Android devices add automatically. For example, Kindle Fire adds a 20px bar with an arrow. Even worse, it seems that initially it is maximized. So we have to deal with resizing events. I found a reasonably good approach at the bottom of this discussion: [link](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/858943)

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I will look into it, and update my answer down the line (it won't be tomorrow!).